# Migrate from jsduck to jsdoc

Tags: javascript, documentation, migrate, jsdoc3, jsduck

I want to migrate lots of JavaScript code which documented with **jsduck** before. and now I want to migrate them all to **jsdoc**.
It would be great if you help me please. Because I can not find any source for that.
So, actually I would also prefer to write a script to do this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I guess first you'll need to familiarize yourself with the [JSDoc documentation](https://jsdoc.app/) and understand all the differences of JSDoc v/s JSDuck syntax.

You can export all that JSDuck knows to JSON files using the `--export` option.

Then you would need to rewrite the doc-comments to express this info using JSDoc syntax. I can suggest tools like [recast](https://github.com/benjamn/recast) or [jscodeshift](https://github.com/facebook/jscodeshift) to perform modifications of parts of JS code (comments) without changing any other parts of the code.

There might be simpler approaches, like regex search-replace of some `@tags`. Though it really all depends on the specifics of how your doc-comments are written.